# Application with a patchable embedded configuration

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang++

I work on a cross-platform C++ application (Visual C++, GCC, clang++ regarding the target platform). I want to embed a configuration string into my application and have possibility to patch the binary after compilation to change the configuration and make it preconfigured.
Now I only consider declaring a configuration variable:

```
const char* embeddedConfig = "*magic*random characters filling the maximum configuration size";
```

Patcher is going to search for the magic in the binary and replace it with the actual configuration.
I am not sure of the stability of the hacky approach. Is there any more reliable way (perhaps compiler-specific)?

Comment: Why don't you just put a default configuration file near the executable?

Comment: There are a lot of cases where it's useful. For example, we have a LogMeIn client executable preconfigured to connect automatically to a specific endpoint. Just download and launch. Seems very useful

Answer (score 1):

That will work if you keep the size of the text unchanged and declare the constant outside of any function. Such constants are simply put into the data section of binary by compiler.

However you will need to re-sign the binary if you are using code signing.

Answer (score 1):

Embed the string as a resource and use the [UpdateResourceA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-updateresourcea) function. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/adding-deleting-and-replacing-resources).

Comment: Ah, fair point. I didn't notice the cross platform requirement.